# MySQL How to do a 3 table join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform a 3 table join on MySQL in order to achieve something like the diagram below.

[image]

The main problem I'm having is that I only want to work with the records of table A which has 100 records so if there are no relationships for the right tables I would like to see a null.

This all works fine when only table A and B are involved but when I try to do the third join with C I'm getting more than the original 100 records, I'm getting 130 which I believe is because is adding the records that match B-C with duplicate data from table A.

What am I missing?

This is the SQL I currently have that returns correctly 100 records

```
SELECT count(A.id)
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON B.id = A.b_id
```

This is what I'm trying to do that is returning more than the original 100 records for Table A.

```
SELECT count(A.id)
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON B.id = A.b_id
LEFT JOIN TableC C ON C.id = B.c_id
```

Comment: Your `left join` solution is correct.  You are getting more rows because you have duplicate references in one of the other tables.

Comment: Hmm that would make sense, is there any way to disregard duplicates if there are more than 1 record that match B - C? Either one of those would work for me as they most likely contain the same information.

Comment: Just wanted to take the time to thank you for your comment. It helped a lot to understand why I was getting more that then original number of records. The solution was to use a sub-query for the second left join.

Comment: ( you are creating a link between B & C, which has nothing to do with A) SO just add a Where clause  that your A.id IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be resolved by a `JOIN` to a subquery rather than a table.

If you had unique Ids to join to, it would simply be like you've tried already (arbitrary example):

```
SELECT * from table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN table3 t3 on t3.id = t2.id
```

If, however the `id` field in `table3` wasn't unique, you'd get multiple rows for each duplicate.   You could resolve this by:

```
SELECT * from table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table3 GROUP BY id) t3 on t3.id = t2.id
```

So, using your example (assuming only the third join has duplicates), something like:

```
SELECT count(A.id)
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON B.id = A.b_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableC GROUP BY id) C ON C.id = B.c_id
```

...should do the trick.  This is down to assumption of your table and data structure, so you might want to make the asterisk more explicit.

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the solution for the problem.

Comment: `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is an abomination that never should have been supported by any database.  Fortunately, MySQL is phasing out support for the construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(distinct A.id)
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B ON B.id = A.b_id
LEFT JOIN TableC C ON C.id = B.c_id
```